# organization of discord bot files

Tags: discord, discord.py, organization

I have a discord bot that is quite large and for readability, i would like to organize into folders.

I have the main file, and the settings file. i am receiving HTTP responses from the main file right now, which is quite hard to read when going through the file. Ideally, I would like the http requests and commands in a different location... Although this is mostly personal preference i figured someone could show me how theirs is organized. I also have functions that do not fit in any such as an embed builder function

Comment: You can split up your bot into separate files and folders using cogs. Heres the docs for them: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/cogs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use cogs to separate your commands into categories/files.**

On you main bot file (bot.py or main.py) write the code that imports os and that loads your cogs files.

On your bot's root folder create a folder called cogs and then a file with the name you want for example utility and give the .py extension, after that the name of the file (*utility.py in this case*) is the one that you gonna put on the list (*list marked with # list*)

```
import discord
import os

# list 
initial_extensions = [
    'cogs.utilty',
]

# the code to load all your cogs
for extension in initial_extensions:
    try:
        client.load_extension(extension)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.', file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exc()

client.run('token')
```

Now on your cogs file (*utility.py*) write the next code.

```
import discord
from discord import client
import os
from discord.ext import commands


class Utility(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is ready!')
```

**Do not forget that you probably need to rewrite most of your code but it's simple things.**
Hope this helps : )
Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html